# Linking to FireBase

Tags: firebase, flutter

After following all the steps on google, after I run the emulator from scratch I get the following message:

[image]

On the google Firebase site it also tells me "Congratulations, you've successfully added Firebase to your app! ". But I am worried I did not do things properly and do not want to run in to problems later.

I do not have any problems uploading the code to the android emulator, hence I do not know if it successfully connected to Firebase. How can I properly check if I am actually indeed connected to Firebase?

Comment: What Firebase, analytics? Firestore? Storage?

Comment: It is better to copy & paste the log.

Comment: I am sorry I am a beginner at this, it was on adding like google-services.json files to the android studio the very beginning part. Or adding "Android App".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check it through your code
Try getting the user by (just for the test)

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.getCurrentUser()//should return null
```

If it throws no error everything is setup correctly

Make sure the emulator has Google play services installed

Comment: You have to check out some tutorial about coding in dart flutter..very easy..just fallow through you'll know where to put the above code

Comment: I am using android studio, can i just simply type this code in to my main.dart file?

Comment: Yes inside a async function..call that function from initState()

Comment: I have my code on the main.dart file, but I am still not sure what to call, I am sorry I am a beginner at dart.

Comment: That's why I suggested fallowing a tutorial..will take u six hours max